# Using Datepicker to Select Date then Display Date Minus One Day

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to use Datepicker to select a date and later display that date minus one day.

For example, in the code below, I'd like the user to be able to select "Sunday, March 15, 2020", but I'd like the  to display "Saturday, March 14, 2020" upon clicking the button.

I've had trouble finding/figuring out the answer. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "DD, MM d, yy",
    minDate: 0,
  });
});

function showDate() {

  var dateOptions = {
    weekday: "long",
    year: "numeric",
    month: "long",
    day: "numeric"
  };
  var selectedDate = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
  var currentLanguage = $("#language option:selected").val();
  var dateClass = document.getElementsByClassName("date");
  for (var i = 0; i < dateClass.length; i++) {
    dateClass[i].innerHTML = selectedDate.toLocaleDateString(currentLanguage, dateOptions);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Please select the event date.</td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30" autocomplete="off"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="showDate()">Show Date/button</button>

<p>Please send the notice on <span class="date"></span>.</p>
```

Comment: Are you looking to do it without adding another library? MomentJS would make this incredibly easy with `date.subtract(1, "days");`

Comment: Great suggestion @ShaunE.Tobias! Looks like Scaramouche used it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I always appreciate a vanilla JS approach, but when it comes to date/time handling, I really can't recommend [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) enough, just like [Shaun said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60699459/using-datepicker-to-select-date-then-display-date-minus-one-day#comment107393745_60699459).

In this case `subtract(1, 'd')` will do the work, and `.format('LL')` will print a locale-aware user-friendly output.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "DD, MM d, yy",
    minDate: 0,
  });
});

function showDate() {

  var dateOptions = {
    weekday: "long",
    year: "numeric",
    month: "long",
    day: "numeric"
  };
  var selectedDate = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
  var currentLanguage = $("#language option:selected").val();
  var dateClass = document.getElementsByClassName("date");
  for (var i = 0; i < dateClass.length; i++) {
    dateClass[i].innerHTML = moment(selectedDate).subtract(1, 'd').format('LL');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Please select the event date.</td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30" autocomplete="off"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="showDate()">Show Date/button</button>

<p>Please send the notice on <span class="date"></span>.</p>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks so much Scaramouche!

Answer (score 1):

add this line

```js
  var dt = new Date(selectedDate);

dt.setDate( dt.getDate() - 1 );

and replace this:

dateClass[i].innerHTML = dt.toLocaleDateString(currentLanguage, dateOptions);

    function showDate() {

      var dateOptions = {
        weekday: "long",
        year: "numeric",
        month: "long",
        day: "numeric"
      };
      var selectedDate = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
      var dt = new Date(selectedDate);
             dt.setDate( dt.getDate() - 1 );
      var currentLanguage = $("#language option:selected").val();
      var dateClass = document.getElementsByClassName("date");
      for (var i = 0; i < dateClass.length; i++) {
        dateClass[i].innerHTML = dt.toLocaleDateString(currentLanguage, dateOptions);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Great solution as well!